Examine the convergence of $\int_0^1x^{n-1}\log x dx.$
Examine the convergence of $\int_0^1x^{n-1}\log x dx.$
The solution given is as follows:
$0$ is the only point of infinite discontinuity of the integrand. Let us examine the convergence of $\int_0^{\frac 12}x^{n-1}\log x.$ The integrand is negative in $(0\frac 12]$.
Let $f(x)=-x^{n-1}\log x,x\in (0,\frac 12].$ Then $f(x) > 0$
for all $x\in (0, \frac 12].$
If $n - 1 > 0,$ the integral $\int_0^{\frac 12}f(x)$ is a proper one, since
$\lim_{x\to 0+} x^r\log x= 0,$ for all $r > 0.$
If $n - 1=0,$ $0$ is the only point of infinite discontinuity of $f·$
Let $m$ be a positive number such that $m + n - 1 > 0.$ Then
$\lim_{x\to 0+}x^{m+n-1}\log x=0.$ Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0+} x^m f(x) = 0.$
Let $g(x)=\frac 1{x^m}, x\in (0, \frac1 2].$
Then $g(x) > 0$ for all $x\in (0,\frac1 2].$
Since $lim_{x\to 0+}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ and $\int_0^{\frac 12}g(x)dx$ is convergent if $m < 1,$ it follows that $\int_0^{\frac 12}f(x)$ is convergent if $m<1.$
Therefore $\int_0^{1}f(x)$ is convergent if $m<1$ and $m+n-1\gt 0,$ i.e if $1-n\lt m\lt 1,$ i.e if $n>0.$
If $n=0$  the integral reduces to $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x}dx.$
$\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{\log x}{x}dx=-\frac12(\log\epsilon)^2\to -\infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0+$ and therefore $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is divergent if $n=0.$
If $n < 0,$ then $x^{n-1}\geq x^{-1}$ for all $x\in (0,1].$ Since the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x} dx$ is divergent, it follows that, $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is divergent.
Hence the given integral is convergent if and only if $n > 0.$

However, there are a couple of thing I don't understand in this solution:

Problem 1:


If $n - 1 > 0,$ the integral $\int_0^{\frac 12}x^{n-1}\log x$ is a proper one, since
$\lim_{x\to 0+} x^r\log x= 0,$ for all $r > 0.$

How is $\int_0^{\frac 12}f(x)$  a proper integral?
It is clear that, $f(x)$ is bounded on $(0,\frac 12].$ However, $f$ is not defined on zero. In order that a function $f$ be integrable in $[a,b];a,b\in \Bbb R,$ the definition of proper integrals suggests that $f$ be bounded on $[a,b]$ which means implicitly that $f$ must be defined on $a.$ But in this case, $f$ is not defined on $0.$
One might say that we may redefine $f$ as $f_R:[0,\frac 12]$ by $f_R(0)=0$ and $f^R(x)=f(x)$ when $x\in (0,\frac 12]$ and then $\int_0^{\frac 12}f_R$ is a proper integral.
But then my question is that, we are talking about $f$ not $f_R.$ The given function is $f$ not $f_R$ so, I don't think we can't just 'redefine' $f$ and be done.

Problem 2:


If $n < 0,$ then $x^{n-1}\geq x^{-1}$ for all $x\in (0,1].$ Since the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x} dx$ is divergent, it follows that, $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is divergent.

I don't understand why is $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ divergent just because $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x} dx$ is so. If $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x} dx$ were convergent then I could have said, $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is convergent as $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$
Any clarifications regarding these two issues will be greatly appreciated.

The problem $1$ is $f(x)$ is  bounded on $[0,1]$. You can define $f(0)=0$ such that $f(x)$ is continous on $[a,b]$. Thus,  it is a proper integral.

The problem you can use this  inequality  $\frac{-\log x}{x^{1-n}}\ge \frac{-\log x}{x}$

@fusheng How is $f(x)$ bounded on $[0,1]$? Precisely, if $f$ is biunded then $\exists  B\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $|f(x)|\leq B$ for all $x\in [0,1].$

Since $\mathop {\lim } \limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x^r\log x=0$, you can find $\epsilon $ and $\delta $ such that $|x^r\log x|\le \epsilon$  for $x\in (0,\delta]$. For $[\delta,\frac{1}{2}] $, $f(x)$ is obviously bounded.

If you perform the change of variables $x = {\rm e}^{ - t}$, the integral becomes $ - \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - nt} t,{\rm d}t}$. This form is easier to analyse.

@fusheng Using your arguments, indeed we can show that $f$ is bounded on $(0,1].$ But the phrase, "$f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ seems to make no sense. That's because, $f$ is not even defined at $x=0.$ And we know for an integral $\int_a^bf(x)$ (, where $a<b$) to be proper $f$ must be bounded in $[a,b],$ from which $f$ is defined at $a$ follows immediately. But here, if $a=0,b=1$ then $f$ is not defined at $0.$ So how's still $f$ a proper integral?

@ThomasFinley You define $f$ to be $0$ at the origin. Then this $f$ is indeed a bounded and continuous function on $[0,1]$.

@Gary Please see my edit. I said I may dedine it like that. But that's not the definition of $f$ given in the question.

@ThomasFinley Changing the value of a function on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ does not change its integral. In particular, $\int_0^1 f =\int_0^1 f_R$.

@Gary The theorem that you just used is valid only when the function $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$. But the function $f$ is not defined at $0$.

You can define $f^\prime(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in(0,1]$ and $f^\prime(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$. Then $\int_0^1{f^\prime\left( x \right) dx}=\int_0^1{f\left( x \right) dx}$. So we  can think $\int_0^1{f\left( x \right) dx}=\int_0^1{f^\prime\left( x \right) dx}$$ is a proper integral.

Because  changing the value of a point does not affect the integral

@fusheng $f'$ is an unfortunate notation (cf. derivative).

A small nitpick: Usually, when one uses $n$ as the index and talks about "convergence" we usually examine what happens as $n\to\infty$. As a parameter, it is better to write $r$ or any other letter.

The questions posed in Problems 1 and 2 were answered in comments, but to make this answer complete, I cover them here.
In Problem 1, for $n\gt1$, the integrand, $x^{n-1}\log(x)$, is bounded on $[0,1]$. Thus, the integral is proper.
In Problem 2, for $n\lt0$, $x^{n-1}\ge x^{-1}$ on $[0,1]$. Thus, $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_0^1x^{-1}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\infty\tag1$$
Here, we evaluate the integral for $n\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^{n-1}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1n\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x^n\tag{2a}\\
&=-\frac1n\int_0^1x^n\,\mathrm{d}\log(x)\tag{2b}\\
&=-\frac1n\int_0^1x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2c}\\[3pt]
&=-\frac1{n^2}\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ prepare to integrate by parts (choose $u$ and $\mathrm{d}v$)
$\text{(2b):}$ integrate by parts ($x^n\log(x)\to0$ at both $0$ and $1$)
$\text{(2c):}$ $\mathrm{d}\log(x)=\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x$
$\text{(2d):}$ integrate
